# Не грузится базовый адрес через App.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Базовый адрес не грузится из App.config

**App.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service>

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="IRequestCourseService" />

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/RequestCourse" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Всё работает, если его задать явно в коде.

```
var baseAddressHttp = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/RequestCourse"); 
using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RequestCourseService.RequestCourseService), baseAddressHttp))            
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Служба доступна по {0}", host.BaseAddresses[0]);
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
            }
```

Comment: А какой у вас код _не_ работает? Что вы вызываете в том случае?

Comment: То-же самый код, но без передачи baseAddressHttp в конструктор.
В этом случай host.BaseAddresses.Count == 0.

Comment: Где размещается служба? Вероятно не видит конфига

Comment: В консольном приложении.
Я положил app.config в одной папке с exe и dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо добавить файл конфигурации (`app.config`) к проекту консольного приложения в VS и в нем провести настройку сервиса (добавить секцию <system.serviceModel>) и все заработает. Visual Studio должно создать такой при компиляции и назвать его `<exename>.exe.config`, он должен попасть в один каталог с `.exe`.

Comment: Да конфиг создается <exename>.exe.config.
Мне почему то кажется, что он не может найти из-за того что я не задал имя сервису в конфиге.

<service name="какое имя здесь должно быть">
</service>

Comment: Твоя правда, только имя должно быть полным путем со всеми namespace до класса службы.

Comment: Всё заработала когда в service name задал <имя сборки>+<имя класса реализующий контракт>